# Why ArrayList<T> can assign to ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, generics

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = getList();
        System.out.println(list.toString());
        list.add(1);
        System.out.println(list.toString());
    }

    public static <T> ArrayList<T> getList(){
        ArrayList<String> strings =  new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("qwert");
        return (ArrayList<T>) strings;
    }
}
```

As the code shown above why it is allowed to assign to ArrayList
JDK11 out put

```
[qwert]
1
```

Comment: I would recommend you to read [Generics in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Comment: Using `(casting)` is like telling compiler "trust me, I know what I am doing". When there is *some* safe scenario for casting then compiler will not complain and everything after it will be programmers fault.

Comment: Casting is bad here. The problem is that casting tells the compiler "I know better than you, so treat this as an array of Integer even though it isn't"

Comment: I am getting an **unchecked cast** warning from the Java compiler when I compile this code. So the compiler does warn after all.

Answer (score 0):

> Why `ArrayList<T>` can assign to `ArrayList<Integer>`

It's because you have provided explicit typecast.

Probably, what you are not able to understand is how `ArrayList<Integer> list` can hold `qwert`. Again, it's because you have asked the compiler to trust you that you are putting `Integer` into it.

Eventually, all the type information is removed when it comes to runtime. You need to understand the concept of [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
return (ArrayList<T>) strings;
```

Here, the String ArrayList is not directly casted to Integer ArrayList, instead, it is casted to T ArrayList. According to 'Target Type Inference' in the docs:

```
static <T> List<T> emptyList();
List<String> listOne = Collections.emptyList();
```

> This statement is expecting an instance of List; this data type is the target type. Because the method emptyList returns a value of type List, the compiler infers that the type argument T must be the value String.